# Sample in Dataflow / Beam with Python

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to get a sample of the items in `PCollection` using the Python SDK on Dataflow / Beam.

While it's not documented, `Sample.FixedSizeGlobally(n)` exists.

When testing, it *seems* to return a `PCollection` with a single item: a list containing the samples, rather than a `PCollection` with the samples. Is that correct?

Is doing this the best way of turning that single-item `PCollection` into a `PCollection` of the items?

```
| Sample.FixedSizeGlobally(sample_size)
| beam.FlatMap(lambda x: x)
```

Comment: Yes, that's the best way. You should add it as an answer, because you've figured it out yourself : )

Comment: OK. Thanks @pablo Could the Beam Gods bless Python with a Sample-Any? And are there docs for these things?

Comment: Sorry about the lack of documentation. We'll address that! What do you mean Sample-Any?

Comment: Thanks. Re Sample-Any, I thought I saw a Java transform that took a PCol and return another PCol with n items (i.e. no need for the FlatMap)...

Comment: Gotcha. Yes. We'll add that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, yes. The `Sample.FixedSizeGlobally()` transform returns a PCollection with a single list element. You can turn it into a PCollection of single elements like you said:

```
Sample.FixedSizeGlobally(sample_size)
| beam.FlatMap(lambda x: x)
```

We'll make sure to add a PC-PC transform - and we also welcome your contributions to Beam : ) - But in the meantime, that's what we've got.

Comment: 15 months later, is there a PC-PC transform available ?