# Sample distribution in Dataflow / Beam with Python

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

The question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47101680/sample-in-dataflow-beam-with-python).

I'm trying to get a sample of the items in PCollection using the Python SDK on Dataflow / Beam.

`Sample.FixedSizeGlobally(n)` exists and results in a PCollection of Iterable.

Suppose I have this:
`pipeline | Sample.FixedSizeGlobally(sample_size) | beam.Map(my_function)`

In this case it is not clear if the whole sample will end up on a single worker and will cause out of memory or if the sample will be distributed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current implementation of the sampling PTransforms (as of Beam 2.4.0) has this problem. If your sample is too big, then it may overwhelm one worker.

It also has the problem of having pretty low parallelism.

Improvements to this transform should come in a few months, and are tracked in [JIRA issue BEAM 3000](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/BEAM/issues/BEAM-3000)